# Código para verificar se determinado valor está dentro de uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Preciso de um programa que dada a quantidade total de baús da partida, uma lista com o número de cada baú e o número escolhido pelo jogador, diga se o número escolhido por ele está na lista ou não. Se o número pelo jogador esteja nessa lista, o código imprimirá "Acertou", caso não esteja, imprimirá "Errou".
A entrada dos dados ficaria assim:

```
4
4 3 5 6
5
```

E aí o código teria que imprimir assim:

```
Acertou
```

Isso foi o que eu fiz até agora, está claramente errado mas não consigo identificar o que:

```
total_baus = int(input())
lista = [input().split()]
palpite_jogador = int(input())
    
if lista[i] == palpite_jogador:
  print('Acertou')
else:
  print('Errou')
```

Comment: `split` já retorna uma lista, então não precisa colocar `[]` em volta (ao fazer isso, vc criou uma lista com outra lista dentro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A expressão que retorna `TRUE` se um valor existe em um container (list, string, dictionary, set, tuple...) é a seguinte:

```
valor in container
```

Então o que você está buscando é:

```
if palpite_jogador in lista:
    print('Acertou')
else:
    print('Errou')
```

Obs.: o seu código também possui o erro apontado pelo [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/554070/c%c3%b3digo-para-verificar-se-determinado-valor-est%c3%a1-dentro-de-uma-lista#comment-986536).

Referências:

Python Software Foundation. Python Language Reference, version 3.10.4. Disponível em https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

edit: Substituída a palavra "indexável" por container, sugerido por  jfaccioni

Comment: Além disso, da forma que foi feito a lista terá strings mas o palpite é um `int`, então precisa converter os elementos da lista antes (ou não converter o palpite)

Comment: Olá @Kalegas, apenas uma correção: em Python não existe o tipo "indexável" - o termo apropriado é `container`. A implementação do método `y.__contains__` é o que permite o uso da sintaxe `x in y`. Virtualmente todos os `containers` são também [iteráveis](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-iterable), e alguns podem também ser [sequências](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-sequence) ou [mapeamentos](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-mapping).